# Where are Node apps deployed using gcloud SDK?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've deployed a Node app to Google Cloud. It works beautifully.

However, where is the app running? Where in the directory structure of my instance is it stored?

I'd also like to identify where stdout is on that process. The logging solution in the GAE console is powerful but excessive for some of the simple debugging tasks I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application runs inside a Docker container and hosted on one or more instances that AppEngine provisioned for you when you deployed your application. AppEngine is managed runtime environment and thus you are not supposed to access the instance/container directly. The internal directory structure is exactly the same as you've built it during the development process.

The stdout is redirected to Google Cloud Logging. You can filter the log by severity (debug, errors, everything etc..) to reduce the amount of data you need to read.

Comment: thanks. that's what i was afraid of. here's the link to the log filters... https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced_filters

Comment: it would be really nice to have a `gcloud log tail` command for the container logs. :)

Comment: finally.... what is the standard logging package that Node devs use on google cloud? the formatting of logme really does not play well with the cloud logging.